# String.replace() is removing parts of my string i didn't tell it to

Tags: java

I have a program that is calculating the value of a sign based on the square footage and a fee per character. I need to remove the whitespaces to accurately count the number of characters, but is using .replace and .replaceAll, i have found that when i print the resulting string, everything after the first whitespace is removed. For example, if I entered "Welcome to java" when user is prompted to assign a value to the String variable, text, textCrop would simply print "Welcome" after the text.replaceAll line runs. What am I doing wrong?

```
    //calculate price of text and add values
            textCrop = text.replaceAll(" ", "");       //heres where I'm trying to remove whitespaces
            System.out.println(textCrop);
            textPrice = ((text.length() + 1)    * 1.45);
            finalPrice = textPrice + sizePrice;
            System.out.print("$");
```

Comment: Are you sure u're not reading a single word instead of a line?

Comment: Did you use `Scanner.next` instead of `Scanner.nextLine`?

Comment: What is `text`? Can you give us some more context? Try printing `text` to see how many spaces it has

Answer (score 0):

This was my code and it worked perfectly for me. You need to read the entire line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = sc.nextLine();
        String textCrop = text.replaceAll(" ", "");       //heres where I'm trying to remove whitespaces
        System.out.println(textCrop);
        double textPrice = ((text.length() + 1)    * 1.45);
        double finalPrice = textPrice ;
        System.out.print("$");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Scanner.nextLine()` when reading the input.

To accurately count the number of characters without white spaces, you should find the length of the *textCrop* and not *text*. `textCrop.length()`